# Is there a way show only groups that meet a specific set of clauses?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble writing a query.
I want to view groups that all match the same 'where' clause.

```
ID  ArticleNumber   Title       Uploaded
1   1000            Item One    1
2   1000            Item One    1
3   2000            Item Two    1
4   2000            Item Two    0
5   2000            Item Two    0   
6   3000            Item Three  0
7   3000            Item Three  0
8   4000            Item Four   1
9   4000            Item Four   0
10  5000            Item Five   0
```

I only want to view ArticleNumbers where all ArticleNumbers have an Uploaded result of 0

I have the following :

```
select ArticleNumber from DB
where Uploaded = 0
group by Article Number;
```

But I know its not correct for what i want.

I know the result should be 3000 and 5000.

Comment: That query looks correct based on "I only want to view ArticleNumbers where all ArticleNumbers have an Uploaded result of 0". Maybe start with just `select ArticleNumber from DB
where Uploaded = 0` to verify (this will give you duplicate `ArticleNumber`s), but to filter them out you could do `SELECT DISTINCT ArticleNumber FROM DB
WHERE Uploaded = 0` or a `GROUP BY` like you're doing now

Comment: `GROUP` groups the results. Do you want it grouped? You could do `select group_concat(ArticleNumber) as Numbers from DB where Uploaded = 0
group by Article Number` which would give all matching IDs in 1 column as CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT ArticleNumber FROM DB
GROUP BY Article Number
HAVING SUM(Uploaded) = 0;
```

So this will only return the Article Numbers for which all the uploaded values are 0